# Drive SDK API insert crash on Android 4.0.4

Tags: google-drive-api

When the below app is run on anoroid, i get message 'unfortunately  it
has stopped'. i have generated the client ID for this package in API
console.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   System.out.println("Getting Creditenal");


   Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,
null, new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null);
   startActivityForResult(intent, CHOOSE_ACCOUNT);
       mContext = this;


  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int
resultCode, final Intent data) {
switch (requestCode) {
case SHOW_EXCEPTION:
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
    AlertDialog ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        ad1.setCancelable(false); // This blocks the 'BACK' button
        mExcep += "--Sag Show Exception";
        ad1.setMessage(mExcep);
        ad1.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        ad1.show();
     }
case CHOOSE_ACCOUNT:
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
         service = getDriveService(credential);
         SaveFileToGoogleDrive();
    }
}
}

private void SaveFileToGoogleDrive() {

     Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              File newFile = new File();
              String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
 Locale.US).format(new Date());

                newFile.setTitle(timeStamp);
            newFile.setMimeType("text/plain");
            String contentStr = "Time,Lat,Lng,Address";

              try {
                      File insertedFile = service.files().insert(
                             newFile, ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain",
contentStr)).execute();
                      //File insertedFile = service.files().insert(newFile).execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            mExcep = e.getMessage();
                            mExcep+=e.getLocalizedMessage();
                            startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
SHOW_EXCEPTION)
                    }
          }
        });
        t.start();
  }

 private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new
    GsonFactory(), credential)
     .build();
  }

 public void showToast(final String toast) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast,
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
```

}

Also no exception message box is displayed, to know why the API fails ?

Comment: Please help in debugging..How to know why the API is causing the crash ?

Comment: Have you followed all steps in the Android quickstart guide? https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: Hi Claudio,First i created app using mail id sagkumar@gmail.com, everything worked fine. Then on the same phone, i used another mail id: geotagtest606@gmail.com. It failed.  Then i created another package with name com.example.geotaglogger for email id geotaglogger@gmail.com. I followed all the steps for this user also.
i.e.at https://code.google.com/apis/console under API access generated the Client ID .

Comment: Under services, enabled the Drive SDK and Drive API. The same code which used to work for sagkumar@gmail.com is not working for geotagtest606@gmail.com. So it is possibel to have two gmail account on an Anoroid phone and based on the selection, data gets uploaded into the respective drive.

Why the API is not throwing any exception what mistake am i making ? is it problem with the authethication or some other problem ?

Comment: there was some problem in the code logic..i corrected it..but i am getting the following exception:

Comment: try {
            File insertedFile = service.files().insert(
                 newFile, ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", contentStr)).execute();
          
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
               startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        }

Comment: i had generated client ID for the package for the gmail account. then why UserRecoverableAuthIOException is thrown ? Apart from generating the Clinet ID, do we need to perform other setting also ?

Comment: adding the following showed some accept form

Comment: catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
               startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        }  what should i do that, the files get uploaded without showing the password form and the accept form ?